# Open-source or low-cost cross-platform video codec library that can be used for commercial purposes and supports RGBA format

Tags: c++, codec

I'm looking for a way to display videos in a 2D game. The videos need to support an alpha-channel so they can be overlayed on top of the other game elements.

Currently I just have a series of PNG files which are decompressed and then flipped through for the animation. This works, but it is a massive memory hog; a 1024x1024 animation that is 5 seconds long at 24 frames per second takes up well over 400MB. And I'm targeting embedded systems, so this is really not good.

I've been looking for some video codecs that can support these requirements, yet so far all I've really been able to come up with that support RGBA are licensed under GPL, so we can't use them in a commercial product.

Any such beast(s) out there?

Comment: don't understand the -1.

Answer (score 0):

Most codecs don't support an alpha channel - the only one I can think of is the QuickTime animation codec, which isn't very popular.

If you only need binary alpha channel (transparent or not) then setting the top bit of one of the color channels is a common approach.

If these are animation type frames then something like MJPEG might work well and there are lots of LGPL licensed mjpeg libs

Comment: I realize that most don't, hence the question. I know HuffYUV does, but it is GPL. So are a couple of others that I know of. QuickTime is a consideration, though it requires some large files to be installed on the system, and we are working with embedded systems with limited storage.

I do need a full alpha channel, not a binary channel. These are offline-rendered animations that need to be displayed over top of the existing game play objects with some dynamic transparency.

Comment: @Gerald - never knew huffyuv could do RGBA, only used it with YUV. Remember though it is the code that GPL not the codec itself, you could use a GPL app to encode a video and implement your own decoder in your app from their specifications of the format

Comment: it can do RGBA, though it is disabled by default in the reference implementation to disambiguate from 32-bit RGB.

In any case, I just ended up rolling my own that probably works better for my particular needs anyway. The animations are just broken up into a grid of blocks (default of 64x64 pixels), and each frame I just store the blocks that changed since the previous frame. Then when rendering on each frame I just update a texture with the changed blocks. My 400+MB animation is now a single 4MB texture plus about 50MB of frame/block data.

Comment: Not quite as good as a proper video codec as far as compression goes, but the performance is much better than anything else that I've tried so far, and 87.5% is good enough for me. Obviously it won't work as good for noisier animations, but our animations are relatively subtle so it's good for us, at least for now.

Comment: @Gerald sounds an excellent soln. Another possible is that if these aren't full color animations (ie no supercomplex reflection) you can reduce the colour space (ie only 4bits/color) or use a pallete of 256 colors and the just an index/pixel

Comment: I've considered something like that, but then I'm left with the problem of expanding the pixels on the fly at run-time to what the rendering system requires, which is going to be pretty slow. Even if I combine it with my current solution and only have to convert 12.5% of pixels per frame, that's still a little more than 3 million color space conversions or palette lookups per second for a 24-fps animation at 1024x1024. Memory is something of a limitation, but processing power is an even greater limitation on our target platform. Tricky balancing act ;)

Comment: A lookup table is incredibly fast and will fit in cache, even the time saving in read into the CPU will be worth it

Comment: Doing anything per-pixel is going to be very slow compared to 16kb block copies, cache or not, especially since the ultimate destination is video RAM where we do not have direct access to the memory address space and have to use the OpenGL 1.4 API. So we would either have to do an API call for each pixel - which is about as slow as it gets - or generate a block of pixels in RAM and THEN do a block copy anyway.